# Is there a way to read all the messages which are already posted in the bot without knowing their respective Conversation IDs

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using directline V3 for testing out a bot inside MS Teams. 
This is a bot showing some messages inside MS Teams.
 Is there a way to read all the messages which are already posted in the bot without knowing their respective Conversation IDs. How to read all the conversations from the bot show in the attached screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On bot side, if we want to save and retrieve all the conversation history, in C# we can implement the `IActivityLogger` interface, and log the data in `Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)` for example:

```cs
public class ActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    public Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        IMessageActivity msg = activity.AsMessageActivity();
        //log here
        return null;
    }
}
```

So if you save data in Azure SQL Database, you can refer to [Saving Bot Activities in Azure SQL Database](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/05/Saving-Bot-Actions-On-Azure-Sql-Server/), and here are some [official examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Logging).

Then in node.js, you can intercept and log messages using middleware:

```js
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        myMiddleware.logIncomingMessage(session, next);
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        myMiddleware.logOutgoingMessage(event, next);
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there any specific API request in directline V3, which can help in retrieving all the messages from the bot ??  In directline V1.1, I found something like "api/conversations/{conversationId}/messages" to retrieve the messages. Is there a same way to retrieve with directline V3 and we don't have the individual "{conversationId}" for each conversations.

Comment: @user8612739, no, I think you've misunderstand the purpose of using directline api, the `api/conversations/{conversationId}/messages` is used for receiving message from specific conversation, it's not for retrieving history messages, and also the directline api are using for the connection between your bot and your own created client.

Comment: My actual problem is, I need to verify whether a particular message has been posted by bot . for example : "sengo mudila assigned ticket #16273 to you". How to retrieve the text of this conversation . I don't have the conversation ID for this Conversation. Is there any way I can retrieve this message through API...

Comment: @user8612739, are you trying to use directline to build your own client and show conversation history like in ms-teams? Your client is not ms-teams?

Comment: No.Actually our bot is installed as an Custom app inside Microsoft teams. Usecase is like, From our web application when i send a mail to a user inside Microsoft team , that mail is displayed as a conversation in our bot. For example "sengo mudila assigned ticket #16273 to you" is posted because I have sent an mail from my web application to the user inside microsoft teams. Internally they are doing this by using some sdk. My actual problem is, I need to verify whether a particular message has been posted by bot . How to retrieve the text of this conversation .

Comment: @user8612739, so the message like `sengo mudila assigned ticket #16273 to you` is sent from bot to user and you may want to retrieve the message which has `ticket #16273`?  If so, you can save the ticket number in your sql together with the conversation using the method in my answer, then for retrieving history, it's just searching from your stored data like searching data from sql database.

Comment: Yes ,  I want to retrieve this message "sengo mudila assigned ticket #16273" and verify if that message was posted by bot successfully inside MS teams.  "If so, you can save the ticket number in your sql together with the conversation using the method in my answer" --- > is this change to be done in our bot code ... can it be done without making changes to the bot code .

Comment: @user8612739, no, sorry, we need to change the bot application's code.